# Implement Java class using JPype and pass it as a parameter

Tags: python, apache-poi, jpype

I use `Apache POI` and `JPype` together to handle some Excel files. I would like to implement a custom Excel formula function to handle an additional logic in Excel formula evaluator.

It is possible by registering a function: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.html

The problem is my app is written in `Python` and I use `JPype` as a wrapper for `Apache POI`. I tried to create Python function that implements `evaluate()` function (as needed in `registerFunction` from docs).

```py
class CeilingMath:
    def evaluate(*args: Any, row: int, col: int) -> int:
        value = int(args[0])
        return numpy.ceil(value)


# registering
FunctionEval = JPackage("org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval")
FunctionEval.registerFunction("CEILING.MATH", CeilingMath())
```

But when I try to register it I get an error:

> TypeError: No matching overloads found for *static* org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval.registerFunction(str,CeilingMath), options are:
> public static void org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.FunctionEval.registerFunction(java.lang.String,org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function)

I understand that types don't match, but I have also no idea how to bypass that or how to create `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function` instance with custom `evaluate()` function implementation...

**[edit]**
I tried to inherit from Java class:

```py
Function = JPackage("org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions").Function

class CeilingMath(Function):
```

But it doesn't work as well...

> TypeError: Java classes cannot be extended in Python

I believe, the only way of doing this is writing implementations directly in Java, compiling it to JAR archive and include during JVM starts.

Comment: [org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Function](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Function.html) is an interface. So your `CeilingMath` would must implement that interface or would must extend one of the classes which implements that interface already. So the main question is: How to manage inheritance using `JPype`?

Comment: @AxelRichter I made an edit. I think this is not possible without writing implementations in Java directly

Comment: that implementation you have does not seem to support the optional 2nd and 3rd params that Excel supports - see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ceiling-math-function-80f95d2f-b499-4eee-9f16-f795a8e306c8

Comment: @PJFanning Yes, I know, but it doesn't matter when I can't even register a function

Comment: It is not possible to be resolved.